# iOS/iPhone app seems to add a color mask/color shade to my text

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, xcode6, apple-watch

I have some colored images and same colored text on an iPhone App screen. The images show as expected, but when I use the same RGB color code on the text, it appears different on the finished app (mostly, a little darker). Why is xcode changing the color I tell it to use? How to get the text color to exactly match the color codes in the images.

Update: Here's a screenshot. I use the color picker from *inside* XCode, to pick the color from the image, so it shouldn't matter which color space I'm using (I'm using the same for both text and image), it still looks different.

[image]

Comment: Can you add some more detail about where and how you are setting the colors? You are likely using the same rgb values but different color spaces.

Comment: Let me check. I'll update soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very popular problem about different colors...

1) Try to use Digital color (native mac application)

[image]

2) Try to off text shadow, if you use it from your label.

3) And, all of its, is not a wright way to resolve this problem, if you want to color like on image you should correct them manually in you code or in interface builder.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've been doing. To manually edit the colors to match. but sometimes it just can't be done, cause one one the values (R/G/B) won't go below say 10. 
This seems like a such a fundamental issue! I wish there was straight answer.

Comment: Yes, of course it's a fundamental issue. You should correct object color, it's not wright. I remember i try to set text color like nav.bar color it will be very funny...